# XPath : How can I select certain nodes with certain data

Tags: xml, xpath, nodes

I have the followng code in xml and I want to Select in XPath the title of the lessons that take place on Monday.How's that possible?(I'm using Notepad++ and nothing works)
  {

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <Schedule> 
                <Lesson>
                        <Title>Maths</Title>
                        <Lecture Classroom="100">
                            <Day>Tuesday</Day>
                            <Time>12:00</Time>
                        </Lecture>
                        <Lecture Classroom="101">
                            <Day>Thursday</Day>
                            <Time>11:00</Time>
                        </Lecture>
                </Lesson>
                <Lesson>
                        <Title>Scientific Computing</Title>
                        <Lecture Classroom="103">
                            <Day>Monday</Day>
                            <Time>09:00</Time>
                        </Lecture>
                </Lesson>
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
/Schedule/Lesson[Lecture/Day = 'Monday']/Title
```

That means

- start with the root `Schedule` element
- get its `Lesson` children
- filter those to get only those that have a child `Lecture` with a child `Day` whose content is `Monday`
- of the `Lesson` elements that remain, get the `Title` child element